# HTTP POST request body returns code 400

Tags: c#, http-headers, http-post, httpwebrequest

I'm using C#.
I'm trying to make a POST request with the following request body:

```
{"taskId":15, "values" : [{"Key": "myKey","Value":"<Items>
<Item>
    <Item id="17362"/>
</Item>
</Items>"}]}
```

And the following code:

```
var postData = "{\"taskId\":15, \"values\" : [{\"Key\": \"myKey\",\"Value\":\"<Items>   <Item>      <Item id=\"17362\"/>    </Item>    </Items>\"}]}"
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);//postData is the reqeust body 

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
     stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

And got the following execption:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

How can i solve it? Thanks!

**Edit:**
The web method signature is: `MyWebMethod(int taskId, Dictionary<string, object> values)`

And the both requests are works for me:

```
{"taskId":15, "values" : 123 }]}
{"taskId":15, "values" : "123" }]}
```

My Web Server is C# WebService (.asmx)

Comment: a 400 http status code is meaning the server doesn't accept your message format. Without knowledge about what message format the server accepts nobody can tell your what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Dr.Fre, you are right, see my question edit.

Comment: and what framework are you using to publish your access point? web api?

Comment: @Dr.Fre, yeah, I'm using WebAPI (my web service is .asmx file)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by replace `"` to `&quot;`.

The disadvantage is that  i need to change my server side to replace again `&quot;` to `"`.